# Why does the completeness of a set imply that functions can be built out of linear combinations of its elements?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, order-theory, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

(Most of my training is in physical sciences, so forgive my question if its trivial)

I read in my course on partial differential equations that the set of eigenfunctions of a regular Sturm-Liouville problem is "complete" and that this implies that any piece-wise smooth function can therefore be expanded in terms of linear combinations of eigenfunctions. Can someone explain in terms a physicist might understand why the completeness of a set implies that functions can be built out of linear combinations of elements of the set? (I have low proficiency in linear algebra or number theory, but evidently substantial calculus)

Comment: Completeness only means that the set of linear combinations is dense in the space. For example, monomials are complete in the space of continuous functions, but there are not always converging expansions over them. To get expansions you need a stronger property, namely that eigenfunctions form a Schauder basis. This follows easily when the set is additionally orthogonal, which is the case for Sturm-Liouville eigenfunctions. Because completeness implies that arbitrarily close approximation exists, and expansion coefficients of the best approximation are computed explicitly as inner products.

Comment: In this context "complete" probably means "[Complete Orthogonal System](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteOrthogonalSystem.html)". See the link and references therein.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is that, if $\{ e_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ is a complete orthonormal subset of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, then $x-\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda}\langle x,e_{\alpha}\rangle e_{\alpha}$ is orthogonal to every $e_{\alpha}$, which would force it to be $0$, and that would give $x=\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda}\langle x,e_{\alpha}\rangle e_{\alpha}$.

By the way, completeness in a Hilbert space is also equivalent to the Parseval identity, $\|x\|^2=\sum_{\alpha\in\Lambda}|\langle x,e_{\alpha}\rangle|^2$, holding for all $x$. I'll let you figure how this is related to the condition of the first paragraph.